# date sorting elastic search

Tags: sorting, date, elasticsearch

This is my field mapping for the date column in question:

```
          "date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "YYYYMMDD"
          }
```

And here is my query:

```
"sort": [{ "date" : { "order" : "desc" } }]
```

It's bringing back results and in the results there is a sorting element in the results array like the following:

```
         "sort": [
          1548028800000
        ]
```

But its very clearly not sorting the sorting the dates properly.
is there anything that I am doing wrong?

----- ANSWER -------

Changed the mapping to the following and it worked.

```
  "date": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyyMMdd"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is normal behavior. Sort values that are returned are all in milliseconds-since-the-epoch as the documentation says:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

Comment: I have a query which im using to test this and when i run this query in desc order the vales in the date column are as follows 1- 20190321, 
2 - 20190619, 
3 - 20070104
Which is wrong. Any idea why it would be returning them like that?

Comment: Not sure if it counts, but the date format You use in your mappings uses capital Y for year and capital D for days. Will you try to adjust it according to the documentation I linked above?